# pre-apend to a text file

Tags: php, linux, scripting, csv

I want to pre-append some text a a CSV file that is created by MySQL.

Basically I want to add the header information for the rows so when the user opens it in Excel they know what each column is.

Whats the best way to do this.  I presume there is some easy linux command that can do this?  I can also do it in the PHP script.  I'd like to know how to do both just for educational purposes.

General setup:

Debian Etc
LAMP website
Cron calls a PHP script which creates the csv file every night.

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do for example this:

```
echo "header information" | cat - data.csv > dataInfo.csv
```

*echo* prints the header, *cat* takes this header from standard input and writes it together with everything from *data.csv* then into *dataInfo.csv*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pre-pending the header text to the data file, start with file which contains the header and then append the data/CSV file to this header file.

Comment: I'm using the MySQL INTO FILE facility.. I don't think it will allow that.

Comment: After you have the data file, append it to a header file? Instead of prepending the header file to the data file? Or concatenate them both, the header file and then the data file, to a third file e.g. by using the cat command?